# How to convert video path to nsdata?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, video

i record the video in my i pad application and then get the path which is save in my ipad

```
 /private/var/mobile/Applications/F1F1F9A4-41FB-4E80-9070-4A9EC8BA8823/tmp/capture-T0x24ae10.tmp.ND2S7e/capturedvideo.MOV
```

i also find this file my organizer.
now i want to convert to this file path into NSData. how i do it?

Comment: i have the same route but manually i try go and not found the `mobile` folder any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strURL];
```

Comment: I'm getting `nil` for videoData

Comment: @Kirit Vaghela getting nil because your strURL is not appropriate

Comment: then what is correct way to get URL, like when you get video from UIImagepickerViewController

Comment: This gives me error *** ASL MESSAGE SIZE (4729329 bytes) EXCEEDED MAXIMIMUM SIZE (2048000 bytes) ***. video is just of 6 seconds. Is there any other way to convert URL to NSData.

Comment: even i am getting nil.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *filPath=@"file_url";
NSData *dt=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
```

Answer (score 2):

i had also same problem

```
NSString *filePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Waterfall_h264" ofType:@"mov"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath1 options:nil error:&error];
```

also i think you may not include video file into link library. goto: **target section** -> **Build Phases tab** -> **compile sources** -> **click on + button** -> **select your video file** -> **clcik on add button**.

now try again...hope this will be useful...:)